# Why does dbase save files with the same name in 3 different extensions(*.mdx, *.dbf, *.dbt)?

Tags: dbf, dbase

I found an old dbase database.
Each "table" has 3 files with the same name but different extensions.

Example:

- user.mdx
- user.dft
- user.dbf

Why are these different.
I can easily open and use the .dft files.
Can I ignore the other ones or will I lose any data with that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dbf

The various files for a dBase database are:

- `.dbf` - the actual data file - contains the table data
- `.dbt` - the memo file for the database, to hold the long texts
- `.mdx` - the index file, which contains the index entries

Comment: it give many more extension's, that can be occur with the same pre-name. like dBase program files (.prg), that the dBase Compiler compile it to ByteCode file to .pro. Like in nearly all languages or systems, the ByteCode and/or object files have different magic header (e.g. The .EXE, and .DLL files begin with same header magic flag MZ followed by other informations like the value for the entry point of the .exe application - but this is a topic, what was not asked for here. So, see this as a note from me, for this suggestions.  Thanks for reading.